# Twitter Background Image

Tags: twitter

I want to upload a custom background for my twitter profile, but when ever I select a new image from my computer and click save it just says waiting for twitter shows a blank page
https://twitter.com/settings/design/update

Please let me know if there is any way I can change  the background image of my twitter

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the instructions on this [page](http://smartblogtips.com/how-to-change-twitter-background-image-and-colors/):

1. Open your Twitter Profile and click **Settings**
2. Click on the **Design** tab
3. Either select a existing theme or click **Change Background Image** to use your own image